# OAuth2 access tokens generated by GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync don't work; previous access tokens still do

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, mailkit

In the code below, if there is no access token file for example@gmail.com, the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync function creates one.  That token is NOT detected as stale by "if (credential.Token.IsStale)", but the await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2); statement throws an exception that states:
"MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d82-20020a254f55000000b00dbd9eee633dsm2147601ybb.59 - gsmtp'"

Why would the token that is automatically provided result in an authentication failure?  I have a previous working token that still works, even after being refreshed. It's just those now generated by GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync that don't work.  I recently added a Google Drive API to the cloud project.  Might that be the problem?

```
  string[] scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };
  UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(OAuth2Credentials).Secrets,
        scopes,
        "example@gmail.com",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true));

  using (var client = new SmtpClient())
  {
     client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

     if (credential != null)
     {
        if (credential.Token.IsStale)
           await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2("example@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
     }
     await client.SendAsync(mailkitMimeMessage);
     client.Disconnect(true);
  }
```